# How to SSH in Ubuntu on a VM to Ubuntu on another VM

Tags: ssh, openssh

I'm new to Linux.
I​ have Ubuntu installed on Virtualbox on my Desktop, and I want to connect to it from Ubuntu installed on Virtualbox on my laptop.

How can I​ do that?
which user name and IP will I be using, given that both Virtualbox runs on a Windows 10 pro OS?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1430279/edit) to provide additional information: What Networking method (NAT, bridged, host-only) have you selected on both Windows 10 Host Virtualbox Settings? Are the Laptop and desktop on the same LAN, and receiving IP addresses from the same router or DHCP server? Or are you doing connecting across the public internet?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSH into Ubuntu VM remotely](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131017/ssh-into-ubuntu-vm-remotely)